# Google Build cloudbuild.yaml deploying python functions best practices

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-build

My project structure is set up as so:

```
cloudbuild.yaml
requirements.txt
functions/
    folder_a/
        test/
            main_test.py
        main.py
```

What would I need to specify in my `cloudbuild.yaml` to take every newly edited function in `functions/`, run their tests, and then sync those functions to Google Cloud Functions? All functions are python37 and use http as their trigger.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not re-run the tests and redeploy every time any code changes? No harm in testing that an updated dependency hasn't broken something old or something that you depended on could have changed.

I'm not sure what testing framework you're using but something like

```
steps:
- name: 'python'
  args: ['pip3','install', '-r', 'requirements.txt', '--user']
# This installs your requirements and `--user` makes them persist between steps

- name: 'python'
  args: ['python3','pytest', 'functions/folder_a/test/'] #run all tests in the tests folder

# Create a task for each function as shown here: https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/bestpractices/testing#continuous_testing_and_deployment
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud']
    id: 'deployMyFunction'
  args: ['functions', 'deploy', 'my-function', '--source' , 'functions/folder_a/main.py', '--runtime' , 'python37' ,'--trigger-http']

# Option B: Write some python that iterates and deploys each function, although I can't seem to find the Cloud Functions in the python SDK SPI.
- name: 'python'
  args: ['python3','deploy.py']
  env:
  - 'PROJECT_ID=${_PROJECT_ID}'
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I get the error `ERROR: (gcloud.functions.deploy) ResponseError: status=[403], code=[Forbidden], message=[The caller does not have permission]` do you know what permissions have to be set up and where?

Comment: Your pipeline runs with a cloud build service account. The pipeline has whatever permissions are allocated to that service account. Best practise is to allocate only the permissions required for that pipeline, and have a seperate service account for another pipeline if it need different requirements. You can find it in IAM assuming you've enabled the CloudBuild API. Here are the docs explaining.

https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/securing-builds/set-service-account-permissions#granting_additional_access

Comment: @Jaboy By specifying 'python' as a name for the first and the second step, doesn't that mean that it will use the same docker image? If yes, why don't we combine them into a single step? What is the purpose of having two steps?

Comment: Sorry I never saw this one. I believe each new command will be executed in a new container with the same volume attached. You could add the two commands together using an && although I feel like the clarity on which part failed when looking at your pipeline steps has more value than the small time saved by combining them.